# Нарушение отображения даты и чисел

Tags: access, ms-access

Помогите разобраться в чем проблема!!! 
При считывании даты с поля ввода на форме, выдает такое (ниже на картинке), в таблице выполненного запроса[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот и сам запрос

```
SELECT

 [Forms]![Договір_страхування_майна]![випад_ДатаУкладення] AS Выражение1, 
Страховик.Код, 
[Forms]![Договір_страхування_майна]![випад_СтраховаСума] AS Выражение2

FROM Страховик
WHERE (((Страховик.Прізвище)=[Forms]![Договір_страхування_майна]![випад_Страховик]));
```

Причем числовое значение ключа (с другой таблицы) отображается правильно, а уже числовое значение введенное вручную, отображается также как и дата !!!
Помогите !! Что делать ????

access 2010

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Задать формат даты для данной ячейки через контекстное меню ячейки (правый клик мышки).

Comment: Лучше обясните подробнее. а то немного не понятно

Comment: @Saidolim Там сразу видно, не как в Экселе.